# chrome removes url path angular

Tags: angularjs

i got this problem with angular when I open the site in Chrome

```
_localhost/angular/_
```

the url changes to

```
_localhost/#_
```

however in firefox everything is as expected

I asume its caused by the routeProvider

```
var Angapp = angular.module('angApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: mainCtrl
    })
        .when('/:catId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/category.html',
        controller: categoryCtrl
    })
        .when('/detail/:detId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: detailsCtrl
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

I hope someone can help me with this and explain what is happening what did i miss.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

when I add

```
 .....
 config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider. $locationProvider){
 .......
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

the routing breaks completely in Chrome and firefox

```
_localhost/angular/#%2Flink_
```

when i remove the *"#%2F"* and reload the page I get a 404 as return
when i hit backspace then the site loads correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that your browser supports `HTML5`. For browsers that don't support HTML5 history API AngularJS will automatically fall back to `hasbang` URLs so no way to `"remove"` the `hash(#)`.

Comment: well its chrome v28 so it should be supported right? 
I changed:
....
$routeProvider.when('/', {... to 
....
$routeProvider.when('/', {... and now it works?
can some one tel me why?

Comment: So your code $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) now working for you. Please point out the changes you made it to work more clearly.